# MUI v5 disableBackdropClick in createTheme equivalent

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In MUI v4, you could globally disable backdrop clicks of modals or dialogs by doing this within `createMuiTheme`

```
props: {
  MuiDialog: {
    disableBackdropClick: true,
  },
},
```

`disableBackdropClick` was removed in v5; is there an alternative for globally disabling backdrop clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [migration guide](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#modal) suggests overriding the close handler and decide whether the `Dialog` can be closed based on the close reason:

```
<Modal
  onClose={(event, reason) => {
    if (reason !== 'backdropClick') {
      handleClose(event, reason);
    }
  }}
```

But if you want to `disableBackdropClick` in `createTheme` globally, you need to disable the `click` event at 2 places: in the `Dialog`'s [root component](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/7a5ef9da4300bbd5eecb35e02b38e8bda1adb0c7/packages/mui-material/src/Dialog/Dialog.js#L242) and  and the `Backdrop` [component](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/7a5ef9da4300bbd5eecb35e02b38e8bda1adb0c7/packages/mui-base/src/ModalUnstyled/ModalUnstyled.js#L270) to prevent the `onClose` callback from being invoked:

```
createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiDialog: {
      defaultProps: {
        onClick: (e) => e.stopPropagation(),
        BackdropProps: {
          sx: {
            pointerEvents: 'none',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]